# SD Card reader problem Arch

Tags: linux, sd-card, thinkpad

I've installed Arch Linux on ThinkPad E470 and I'm facing some SD card reader problems.

I can read and write from card, but when I'm, working with the card, there are some random lags and computer freeze for a second or two.

For now Google did not helped. This is what kernel says every few minutes. The card is working in my other (older) machines without any problems.

```
[ 3819.841392] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
[ 3820.984122] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 3820.984290] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDXC card at address 59b4
[ 3820.984418] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 SD000 120 GiB 
[ 3831.241070] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 3831.241075] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 3831.241080] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000008 | Version:  0x00000603
[ 3831.241084] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
[ 3831.241089] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[ 3831.241093] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[ 3831.241098] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[ 3831.241102] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[ 3831.241107] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[ 3831.241111] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[ 3831.241115] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000004 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[ 3831.241120] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x25f8c8bf | Caps_1:   0x00002077
[ 3831.241124] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x005800c8
[ 3831.241129] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
[ 3831.241133] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000800
[ 3831.241136] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[ 3831.241140] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x37400208
[ 3831.241141] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[ 3831.241744] mmcblk0: error -84 sending status command, retrying
[ 3831.292067] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 3831.292287] mmcblk0: error -84 sending status command, retrying
[ 3831.343034] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 3831.343229] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x900
[ 3831.343231] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x0, card status 0x0
[ 3831.917030] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 3841.992991] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 3841.992994] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 3841.992999] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000008 | Version:  0x00000603
[ 3841.993004] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
[ 3841.993008] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[ 3841.993013] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[ 3841.993017] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[ 3841.993021] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[ 3841.993026] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[ 3841.993030] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[ 3841.993035] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000004 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[ 3841.993039] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x25f8c8bf | Caps_1:   0x00002077
[ 3841.993044] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x005800c8
[ 3841.993048] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
[ 3841.993052] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000800
[ 3841.993055] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[ 3841.993059] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x37400208
[ 3841.993060] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[ 3841.993209] mmcblk0: error -84 sending status command, retrying
[ 3842.044004] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 3842.044201] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x900
[ 3842.044203] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x0, card status 0x0
[ 3842.044208] mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
[ 3842.056999]  mmcblk0: p1
[ 3934.384760] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
```

EDIT:

```
[user@e470-arch ~]$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2109 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[user@e470-arch ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

And also this:

```
[    0.686312] sdhci-pci 0000:02:00.0: SDHCI controller found [1217:8621] (rev 1)
[    0.686405] sdhci-pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    0.687346] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
```

Comment: Looks like new kernel did the trick, now:         [user@e470-arch ~]$ uname -a
Linux e470-arch 4.15.14-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 28 17:34:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
And it's OK.

Comment: OK it did not solved the problem. Only one reboot it was OK, now it's buggy again.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling upon this, this worked for me:

I have a Thinkpad E480 exhibiting "Error -84 / Tuning timeout" problems; running Xubuntu 18.04.
After some digging through the driver code, I tried the module quirks flag related to clock tuning (SDHCI_QUIRK2_TUNING_WORK_AROUND).

After rmmod of sdhci and sdhci_pci I reloaded it thus - card comes up without errors:

`sudo modprobe sdhci "debug_quirks2=0x1000"; sudo modprobe sdhci_pci`

FWIW there are more flags related to the clock / delay, you can check sdhci.h for the full list (with one line of comment each).

Answer (score 2):

One cause of this problem is when your sdhci driver is "too fast". Inserting a small delay after enabling the device clock (`sdhci_enable_clk`) can "fix" some cards.

On recent kernels a workaround for this problem can be enabled in the device tree for arasan host controllers. See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=26c312281336b55eba01ea1e7b85740d383076c6

Comment: Thanks for reply. That could be solution. Is there way to do it automatically? Removing module and adding it again works until next restart / suspend.

Comment: arasan controllers need a device tree. So your device tree should enable the workaround if necessary. If your controller is not arasan, the mentioned patch does not help in any way.

Comment: Hi. How does one exactly insert this small delay after enabling the device clock? Can you elaborate on how to do this? Thanks.